# Merge two values and remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I want to merge the values *Account details* and *Account specifics* when accounting for which department it is in, and  then remove any duplicate processes resulting from the merge. In this example, *Account specifics* in the HR department will cause a duplicate when merged with *Account details* in the HR department, since both of them perform *Process2*. The duplicate will be removed.

I have tried a lot with pd.groupby to solve this problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is what it looks like now:

```
    Name                 Department       Process
0   Account details      HR               Process1
1   Account details      HR               Process2
2   Account details      Finance          Process1
3   Account specifics    HR               Process2
4   Account specifics    Finance          Process2
5   Account specifics    Retail           Process1
```

Here is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Account details", "Account details", "Account details", "Account specifics", "Account specifics", "Account specifics"],
                     "Department": ["HR", "HR", "Finance", "HR", "Finance", "Retail"],
                     "Process": ["Process1", "Process2", "Process1", "Process2", "Process2", "Process1"]})
```

This is the desired output (with *Account details* as the merged result):

```
    Name                 Department       Process
0   Account details      HR               Process1
1   Account details      HR               Process2
2   Account details      Finance          Process1
3   Account details      Finance          Process2
4   Account details      Retail           Process1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simplest is assign same values to `Name` column and remove duplicates:

```
df = df.assign(Name = 'Account details').drop_duplicates()
print (df)
              Name Department   Process
0  Account details         HR  Process1
1  Account details         HR  Process2
2  Account details    Finance  Process1
4  Account details    Finance  Process2
5  Account details     Retail  Process1
```

If necessary, specify the column to check for duplicates:

```
df = df.assign(Name = 'Account details').drop_duplicates(subset=['Department','Process'])
```

See more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).